# Complicated Sql join query with some condition to get one of the column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I have 2 tables

Table1:

```
Id | product | price
---+---------+------
1  |    A    |  5 
1  |    B    |  3
1  |    C    |  6
```

Table2:

```
Id | prod | subprod
---+------+--------
1  |  A   |  xxxx
1  |  A   |  yyyy
1  |  A   |  zzzz
```

My result table should have all 3 rows from table2 along with a new column called price ( which will be calculated value from table1)

Result table should look like

```
Id|prod|subprod|price
--+----+-------+-----
1 | A  | xxxx  |(if subprod = xxxx in table 2 then this should have price of A from table 1)
1 | A  | yyyy  |(if subprod = yyyy in table 2, then if price of B is greater than price of C then the value should be price of B else 0)
1 | A  | zzzz  |(if subprod = zzzz in table 2, then if price of B is less than price of C then the value should be price of C-B else 0)
```

---

Comment: do you want the whole if Statement in your Output, or do you want the solution to the if Statement? also what have you tried so far? post your query

Comment: looks like homework

Comment: @RealCheeseLord I have created a function with all this hard coded and calling it every time in the query

Comment: @RuslanK. This is real work problem.. not home work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct tab_2.*,case when tab_2.subprod ='xxxx' then (select tab_1.price from tab_1 where product='A') 
 when tab_2.subprod ='yyyy' then CASE WHEN  ( select price from tab_1 where product='B') > ( select price from tab_1 where product='C') THEN ( select price from tab_1 where product='B') else 0 end
 when tab_2.subprod ='zzzz' then CASE WHEN  ( select price from tab_1 where product='B') < ( select price from tab_1 where product='C') THEN ( select price from tab_1 where product='C') - ( select price from tab_1 where product='B') else 0 end
 END AS price
from tab_1,tab_2
where tab_1.Id =tab_2.id
```

Output:-

```
id  prod    subprod     price
1   A       xxxx        5
1   A       yyyy        0
1   A       zzzz        3
```

**EDIT:**

```
 select distinct tab_2.*,case when tab_2.subprod ='xxxx' then (select tab_1.price from tab_1 where product='A') 
 when tab_2.subprod ='yyyy' then CASE WHEN  b.price > c.price THEN b.price else 0 end
 when tab_2.subprod ='zzzz' then CASE WHEN  b.price < c.price THEN c.price - b.price else 0 end
 END AS price
from tab_1,tab_2,( select id,price from tab_1 where product='B') b,( select id,price from tab_1 where product='C')c
where tab_1.Id =tab_2.id
and b.id =tab_2.id
and c.Id =tab_2.id
```

Comment: This works.. is there a way that we can use the cAse statements in a better way.